# Firebase snapshot reference won't return data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using firebase and have a list of people, with certain priorities. In one of my functions, setting and getting priorities is working fine. But in another, I can only set and trying to get the priority of the item returns 'dataSnapshot.getPriority() is not a function'.

```
var playersList = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/players') 
var winnerSnapshot =  playersList.child(winner);
winnerSnapshot.setPriority('1300'); //This is working
var oldPriority = winnerSnapshot.getPriority(); //Not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two different types of object at play here.  A [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/firebase.html) reference, and a [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/datasnapshot.html).  When you call new Firebase(), you get a Firebase reference which allows you to write data (e.g. using set or setPriority) or attach callbacks for *reading* data (e.g. using on or once).

These callbacks registered with on() or once() receive the data via a DataSnapshot and you can call .getPriority() on *that*.  Check out the [Reading Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html) docs for full details.

For example, to make your example work, you could do something like:

```
var winner = "somebody";
var playersListRef = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/players') 
var winnerRef =  playersListRef.child(winner);

// You use a firebase reference to write data.
winnerRef.setPriority('1300');

// You can also use a firebase reference to attach a callback for reading data.
winnerRef.once('value', function(winnerSnapshot) {
  // Inside your callback, you get a DataSnapshot that gives you access to the data.
  var priority = winnerSnapshot.getPriority();
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.  If I call 'once' like that though, will it fire when called, or only when the data changes?

Comment: For anyone else it fires when called.

Comment: Yeah, .once() retrieves the data and fires once.  If you want it to also fire every time the data changes, use .on() instead.